# Maven JavaDoc plugin uses wrong source value

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

We setup the compiler plugin in a dedicated parent pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But the javadoc plugin (version 2.9.1) fails with error:
`error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7`
If i run with "-X" i only see that indeed source is set to 1.7: `source = 1.7`

So the question is why?

(the normal build works fine!)

I also tried to explicitly set source either by property `maven.compiler.source` or by plugin configuration - i put the compiler plugin configuration from above into the project.

So how to get it working?

Comment: It look like you are using a JDK 7 tom compile?

Comment: the code compiles and runs fine (mvn install), only the javadocplugin has problems.

Comment: Ah than you need to upgrade maven-javadoc-plugin 2.10.4 ?

Comment: this didn't help - (i had some hope because you answered ;-))